# How do I insert returned JSON data in a table, coming from an API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

So I have a table with the FORM element:

```
<table id="example" class="sortable">
        <caption><h3><strong>Product inventory list</strong></h3></caption>

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Purchase date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
                <form id="myForm" action="http://wt.ops.few.vu.nl/api/xxxxxxxx" method="get">
                <td> 
                        <input type="text" name="name" required>
                </td>   
                <td>
                        <input type="text" name="category" required>
                </td>
                <td>
                        <input type="number" name="amount" required>
                </td>
                <td>
                        <input type="text" name="location" required>
                </td>
                <td>
                        <input type="date" name="date" required>
                </td>
                <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
                </td>
                </form>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

The information I fill in gets send to my API link, but now I need to append the information I fill in, directly in the table.

I know I can send an AJAX GET request, to get the information stored in the API, but how do I insert the returned JSON data into the table?

Comment: For a start, you need to add id tags to each input. Otherwise, how will the code know where to place the values returned from the API? Then google javascript getElementById

Comment: @Reisclef `document.querySelector`, `document.getElementsByClassName`, etc. are all alternatives to adding `id` attributes to the table.

Comment: True, I stand corrected. Agreed on class name, or querySelector as alternatives. However, there might be no guarantee the API order would fit with the GUI by index. While class could work, seems out of place.  I shouldn't have worded it as "need to", rather than "you might".

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values of

```
<input id= "nameid" type="text" name="name" required>
```

with

```
var value = $("#nameid").val();
```

or set it with

```
$("#nameid").val("myname");
```

Comment: Might want to do this in plain JS (in addition to your jQuery perhaps), as OP didn't tag as jQuery.

Comment: Well, the question clearly *is*  tagged jquery now, so, why should anyone want to make it any harder than necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery ready or button click event to load data. Below code snippet is demonstrates loading of data automatically once the HTML document is loaded. Hope this answers!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Product Inventory List</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<table id="products" class="sortable" border='1'>
<caption><h3><strong>Product inventory list</strong></h3></caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Purchase date</th>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>

var api = 'http://example.com/api/v1/products';

$(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery.support.cors = true;

  $.ajax(
  {
      type: "GET",
      url: api + '/products',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {

        var trHTML = '';                
        $.each(data.products, function (i, item) {            
          trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data.products[i].name + '</td><td>' + data.products[i].category + '</td><td>' + data.products[i].amount + '</td><td>' + data.products[i].location + '</td><td>' + data.products[i].pdate + '</td></tr>';
        });        
        $('#products').append(trHTML);

        },

        error: function (msg) {            
          alert(msg.responseText);
        }
    });
})

</script>

</body>
</html>
```